# series data needs to be sorted on x values for series name: Idle Rickshaw javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, charts, rickshaw

i am getting error in rickshaw

> series data needs to be sorted on x values for series name: Idle

i have a JSON data.Then i am creating a JS Object for series below.
  i am getting the follow error

> series data needs to be sorted on x values for series name: Idle

```
 res.metrics.cpu.Wait= res.metrics.cpu.Wait.map(
                        function (map) 
                        {
                          return { x: map[1], y: map[0] };
                        });


  log(res);
  var metrices = [];
  cpu = {}
  cpu.Wait = res.metrics.cpu.Wait;
  cpu.Idle = res.metrics.cpu.Idle;
  cpu.Nice = res.metrics.cpu.Nice;
  cpu.System = res.metrics.cpu.System;
  cpu.User = res.metrics.cpu.User;
  metrices.push(cpu);

  var parsed = cpu;    



            var series = [];
            var Idle ={};
            Idle.name ="Idle";
            Idle.color = "steelblue";
            Idle.data = parsed.Idle;

            var Wait ={};
            Wait.name ="Wait";
            Wait.color = "steelblue";
            Wait.data = parsed.Wait;

            var Nice ={};
            Nice.name ="Nice";
            Nice.color = "steelblue";
            Nice.data = parsed.Nice;

            var System ={};
            System.name ="System";
            System.color = "steelblue";
            System.data = parsed.System;

            var User ={};
            User.name ="User";
            User.color = "steelblue";
            User.data = parsed.User;

 series.push(Idle);
            series.push(Wait);
            series.push(Nice);
            series.push(System);
            series.push(User);




var graph = new Rickshaw.Graph({
              element: document.querySelector("#chart"),
              renderer: 'line',
              width: 580,
              height: 250,
              series: series
              });

             graph.render();
```

attaching json file 
[enter link description here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9dPxvaFYw2EeWZvTkV5OUhyR1U/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

Though there should be some documentation regarding error.

This problem is due to x and y axis.
Rickshaw in this case is looking for a sorted X axis and the Y can be plotted in arbitary way.
Due to unsorted x Axis this error will always come up.
I realized this thourgh trial and error run.

I hope this answers helps others in case anyone comes across this issue.
For any graph it is good to have sortable X Axis.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my theory, as I also encountered this issue.

Rickshaw expects data on the x axis to be ordered. For some reason, I had my axis switched so `x` values were not sequential. I swapped my axis so all `x` data was ordered and that resolved the issue.

Visually:

```
[
    {"x": 1, "y": 2}, 
    {"x": 3, "y": 5},
    {"x": 2, "y": 8}
]
```

The above will fail because `x` should be `1, 2, 3` not `1, 3, 2`

Either correct it so `x` goes `1, 2, 3` or make `y` the `x` values and vice versa.